# Find 'average' with equal upper and lower distance to values of a given set

Tags: algorithm, math, distance

I recently encountered the following
**problem:**

Given a set of points with height yᵢ, find the height of the line for which the average distance to points above equals the average distance to points below the line:

[image]

More abstract definition: Given a set of real valued data points Y = {y1, ..., yn}, find ȳ which splits Y into two sets Y⁺ = {y ∊ Y : y > ȳ} and Y⁻ = {y ∊ Y : y < ȳ} so that the average distance between ȳ and elements of Y⁺ equals the average distance between ȳ and elements of Y⁻.

**Naive solution**: Initialize ȳ with the average of Y, compute average upper and lower distances and iteratively move up or down depending on whether the upper or lower average distance is greater.

**Question:** This problem is pretty basic, so there is probably a better solution (?) Even a non-iterative algebraic algorithm?

Comment: What about points whose y-coordinate *equals* that of ȳ? Those are not included in your sets Y⁺ and Y⁻, so it seems that ȳ splits Y into *three* sets, one of which seemingly ignored. If they are included in both sets they would change the average distances.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Good point, any solution is fine. So either include them one, both or no set, as long as the algorithm is fast / simple.

Comment: If you know which points are above and below the line because there is a gap, then it is very simple. But if you don't then what happens if a point is on the line?

Comment: It isn't 100% clear that a solution always exists. There is a discontinuity when a point moves from below the line to above the line, the denominators in the average jump. Another way to see the problem is that you can algebraically solve for what the point would have to be if it lies between two successive `y` (it is a simple linear equation) but I don't see any way of proving that the resulting point lies between those 2 `y` at least once.

Comment: @JohnColeman You are right, it still needs to be shown that there is at least one solution and that an iterative algorithm finds that solution in a finite number of steps. Maybe I'll add that later.

Comment: @le_m I've convinced myself that it is true and have a sketch of the proof, but need to make it more rigorous. The idea is that the distance between successive candidate `y_bar` is less than the distance between the corresponding successive `y`, so that if the `y_bar` is above the interval between two successive `y` at one stage, it can't jump to below the interval between the next pair of successive `y` at the next. Thus a sort of discrete analogue of the intermediate value theorem holds. But, as I said, it isn't rigorous yet and I may have overlooked something.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, *if you know which points are above and below the line*, then you can solve it like this:

a = number of points above the line

b = number of points below the line

sa = sum of all y above the line

sb = sum of all y below the line

Now we can create the following equation:

```
(sa - a * y) / a = (b * y - sb) / b              | * a * b
sa * b - a * b * y = a * b * y - a * sb          | + a * b * y + a * sb
sa * b + a * sb = 2 * a * b * y                  | / (2 * a * b)
==> y = (a * sb + b * sa) / (2 * a * b)
      = sa / (2 * a) + sb / (2 * b)
      = (sa / a + sb / b) / 2
```

If we interprete the result then we could say it is the average between the averages of the points above and below the line.

Comment: Combining your answer with a good initial estimate and iterative updates gives a slightly improved algorithm compared to the naive solution.

Answer (score 1):

An iterative solution based on [maraca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43174693/1647737):

**Initialize** ȳ with the mean of the given values.

1. **Split** the given values into those **above** and **below** ȳ.
2. **Calculate** the **new optimal** ȳ for this split.

**Repeat** until ȳ **converges**.

This is slightly faster than the algorithm outlined in the question.

```js
// Find mean with equal average distance to upper and lower values:
function findEqualAverageDistanceMean(values) {
  let mean = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / values.length,
      last = NaN;

  // Iteratively equalize average distances:
  while (last != mean) {
    let lower_total = 0,
        lower_n = 0,
        upper_total = 0,
        upper_n = 0;

    for (let value of values) {
      if (value > mean) {
        upper_total += value;
        ++upper_n;
      } else if (value < mean) {
        lower_total += value;
        ++lower_n;
      }
    }
    last = mean;
    mean = (upper_total / upper_n + lower_total / lower_n) / 2;
  }
  return mean;
}

// Example:
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    points = Array.from({length: 100}, () => Math.random() ** 4),
    mean = points.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / points.length,
    equalAverageDistanceMean = findEqualAverageDistanceMean(points);

function draw(points, mean, equalAverageDistanceMean) {
  for (let [i, point] of points.entries()) {
    ctx.fillStyle = (point < equalAverageDistanceMean) ? 'red' : 'green';
    ctx.fillRect(i * canvas.width / points.length, canvas.height * point, 3, 3);
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(0, canvas.height * mean, canvas.width, .5);
  ctx.fillRect(0, canvas.height * equalAverageDistanceMean, canvas.width, 3);
}

draw(points, mean, equalAverageDistanceMean);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="200">
```